# Android app with support library, which code execute on run time on newer OS

Tags: android, android-support-library

Even that this is a general question, I'll ask it with an example that it would be easier to understand.

Scenarios:

1. I'm using support library 7 and using the action bar feature. A user is installing the app on a device with Android 2.2 (API 8).
2. I'm using support library 7 and using the action bar feature. A user is installing the app on a device with Android 4.3 (API 18).

It is obvious that at run time scenario 1 would run the code of the supported library. But what will happen on scenario 2? Would it run the OS code or the support library code.

I really hope that it runs the OS code.

**EDIT** 
I know that the way Java work is that methods are resolved by their fully qualified name determined at build time (as @adelphus wrote). And therefore the Support library code will run. But if I was the one that implementing the support library, I would have been doing the following:

1. Check the version of the OS on run time
2. In case that the OS has the current object/method I would call to the OS implementation (Actually in this case the support library is only a wrapper for the OS functionality).
3. In case that this is an old OS, I would have implementing the behavior myself

So, does it act on newer version as a wrapper, or on both cases it using the internal implementation?

Thanks

Comment: It's definitely optimized to use the os code when it can.

Comment: @danny117 Did you find any documentation stating this, or you just believe that they did?

Comment: Yes @goBeepit dev You must read the documentation your self.

Comment: @danny117 I read it, looked for it and didn't see any mention for this point. I also checked this site for this answer before posting it. I understand that sometimes there are questions about main functionality, that it is clear the person didn't open the documentation, since it is written all over the place. But this is not the case here, and the purpose of this site is to ask questions like I did. Besides, when writing a good answer (also for other people, since the answer is not for me only) it is conventional to supply links to whatever you say. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7659/197728.

Comment: Now I don't know if I'm mistaken about the support library using actual code when possible.

Comment: @danny117, What do you mean? Does it stated in the documentation or not?

Answer (score 1):

It will run the support library.

The way Java (and therefore Android Apps) work is that methods are resolved by their fully qualified name determined at build time. Since you would have built the App against the support library, that is what will be called, regardless of the version of Android it is executing on.

In reality, it should make no difference to the end user. The point of the support libraries is to provide the same behavior for older versions of Android which don't have the functionality of the new versions. Why would you care whether it is calling the support library or not if the end result is the same?

Comment: thanks. I edited my question to better explain what I meant. I believe that it is implemented as a wrapper for the OS in newer version, as the question suppose, but I'm not sure.